# Can we add event from top-bar calendar on Ubuntu17.10?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, calendar

I just got Ubuntu 17.10 and I found there are huge changes on UI.

The top-bar calendar with Evolution is very helpful while I could not add/modify the event.

So, is there any way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Press super key or windows key then search "calendar".
Left click on any day in which you want to add event.
Then add event by filling up details.**

*This worked for me.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Gnome Calendar" program to add/modify the event. Click on the Activities link (or press the Super key), type "Calendar" to get the program. If the program is not installed, use the Ubuntu Software Center to install it.

Comment: Right, I know this but I would like to deal with my event on top-bar calendar directly. It seems like it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: Do you know if this has been fixed in recent versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: i feel the same. The current behaviour is counter intuitive and should be improved